# Send email in codeigniter with domains

Tags: codeigniter, email

I tries to send email using codeigniter. I sent to gmail (@ gmail.com) successfully but not for other domains example (@ example.com).  is there anything that could help me ??

following my code

```
$this->email->from($data['email'], 'Report');
$this->email->to('biosm.sa@gmail.com', 'hasan@example.com');
$this->email->set_mailtype('html');
$this->email->subject('Report '.$data['first_name'].' '.$tgl_report);
$this->email->message($report);
$this->email->send();
```

Comment: Did you checked your code for errors? There is a `'` missing right after @example.com.

Comment: I get print like code in bottom..

Answer (score 0):

I get print debugger like buttom this :

Your message has been successfully sent using the following protocol: mail

From: "Report"

Return-Path:

Reply-To: "hasan@example.com"

X-Sender: hasan@example.com

X-Mailer: CodeIgniter

X-Priority: 3 (Normal)

Message-ID: <546066ca6a564@example.com>

Mime-Version: 1.0

Content-Type: multipart/alternative; boundary="B_ALT_546066ca6a5b9"

=?utf-8?Q?Report_Mujahid_12/11/2014?=

This is a multi-part message in MIME format.

Your email application may not support this format.